# Mysql how is ISNUMERIC() available?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, isnumeric

In MSSQL i am using query like below, and it will make different queries depending what i have in $search: text or numbers.

```
$query="
                IF (isnumeric('$search')=0)
                SELECT *
                FROM giper
                WHERE `name` LIKE '%$search%'
                ORDER BY `art`, `name`
                LIMIT 20

                ELSE
                SELECT *
                FROM giper
                WHERE `art` LIKE '$search%'
                ORDER BY `art`, `name`
                LIMIT 20";
```

How i can do the same in MySQL?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to note that your code is unsafe and prone to SQL Injections, better use PreparedStatements or its equivalent in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this can help you

```
            SELECT *
            FROM giper
            WHERE `name` LIKE '%$search%' OR `art` LIKE '$search%'
            ORDER BY `art`, `name`
            LIMIT 20
```

or

```
   SELECT *
          FROM giper
          WHERE if ('$search'=0 ,`name` LIKE '%$search%' , `art` LIKE '$search%')
          ORDER BY `art`, `name`
          LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1):

In **SELECT** statement, you can use **OR** within the **WHERE** condition, it could be

```
   SELECT * FROM giper
      WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' OR art LIKE '$search%'
      ORDER BY art, name LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get SELECT as You wish only for not numeric `$search` val

```
SELECT * FROM giper
WHERE (name LIKE '%$search%' OR art LIKE '$search%')
and '$search' NOT REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
ORDER BY art, name LIMIT 20
```